# Surprising Array index error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape through a website, and I am getting an error which I am not able to understand. It says index out of bounds fro the 11th line, but I'm not sure why that would happen or how to fix it. Somebody pls hlp.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=example')
data = site.read()

parsed = BeautifulSoup(data)
topics = parsed.findAll('div', {'id': 'zero_click_topics'})[0]
results = topics.findAll('div', {'class': re.compile('results_*')})

print(results[0].text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/James/Documents/Superman/suDuk.py", line 11, in <module>
    topics = parsed.findAll('div', {'id': 'zero_click_topics'})[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: There's no <div id="zero_click_topics"> on the page you're loading

Comment: @BrovisMann: I didn't downvote but you could have checked that yourself.

Comment: Downvotes are not hate. They are a signal that something is wrong.  In this case, your question is equivalent to asking why `[][0]` fails.  Debugging hint: if obj[n] fails, temporarily replace it with `print(obj, n)` to see why.

Answer (score 0):

If `findAll` doesn't find any, there won't be a first element to index.  As to why it wouldn't find any, you haven't provided nearly enough information to answer that.